# Show hidden items if they match search term

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, search

Is it possible to search through hidden items (I used CSS `display: none;` property) using JS? I want to show only the first 50 items from my array (the rest is visible if the user clicks the "Show all" button). In addition to this, I want to enable the user to search through the all items from that list using the search bar I created. So far, I managed to limit the number of items shown, and create a search bar and search function. However, my search function only finds the results from the visible 50 items. How can I create a function that will show items from the hidden specter of my array if there are any matches?

Relevant JS code:

```
function filter_shown(el) {
    var filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue;
    input = document.getElementById('myInput');
    filter = el.value.toUpperCase();
    ul = el.parentElement.nextElementSibling
    li = ul.getElementsByTagName('li');
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
        if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            li[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            li[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

Relevant PHP + CSS code:

```
<?php
foreach ($items as $item){
    if ($i++ == 50){ ?>
        <style>
            li{display:none;}
            li:nth-child(-n+50){display:list-item;}
        </style>

    <?php } ?>
    <li> <?php echo $item?> </li>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: I can’t help you with your specific problem, but I can tell you that I personally avoid setting CSS properties in JS and instead set CSS classes only. This keeps a clear separation of display and logic. For instance, when clicking “show all” you could just add a class of “show-all” to the parent UL and the display logic can be a simple CSS ruleset.

Comment: For this specific problem the PHP should be relevant, just a sample of the HTML output is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by adding or removing class in javascript. If you define "display:none" in css for the class you added, the content will appear when the class is removed.

#PHP

```
<?php
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($items as $item){
      $i++; ?>
        <li class="<?php echo $i >= 50 ? 'hidden' : '' ?>"> <?php echo $item ?> </li>
<?php } ?>
```

#CSS

```
li.hidden{
  display:none;
}
```

#JAVASCRIPT

```
/* You can use "pure javascript" here if you wish. I used jquery to make the job easier.
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
*/
         $(document).on("keyup",'#myInput',function () {
              let searchText = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
              if(searchText.length >= 1){
                  $("li").each(function () {
                      var str = $(this).text().toLowerCase().trim();
                      if(parseInt(str.search(searchText)) >= 0){
                          $("li").addClass("hidden");
                          $(this).removeClass("hidden");
                      }
                  })
              }else{
                  $("li").removeClass("hidden");
              }
          });
```